# Сервис перезапускается при закрытии приложения

Tags: java, android

Стартую сервис таким образом:

```java
Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Service.class);
startService(i1);
```

Вод такой код `onStartCommand()`:

```java
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    System.out.println("2 Сервис запущен");
    start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

В манифесте

```xml
<service android:name=".RoosterConnectionService">

</service>
```

Сервис стартует, работает, но при закрытии приложения сервис перезапускается. Как сделать, что бы сервис не прерывался?

Comment: С чего вы взяли что он перезапускается? Возможно он отлично функционирует. Во вторых: стоит учитывать факт того что он может быть убит системой и соответственно перезапустится.

Comment: Мой сервис конектится с сервером, если верить логам, то после закрытия приложение устанавливает новое соединение и продолжает работать в фоне пока я не открою и не закрою приложение, соединение сбрасыватся и снова конектится

Comment: Напишите в манифесте android:process. Но советую почитать изменения с 8 андроида о фоновых сервисах и о foreground сервиса. Так же о JobSheduler

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна "бэкграундная" работа, могу посоветовать WorkerManager почитать можно тут https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/562-urok-29-workmanager-vvedenie.html